# How to Install Lexmark x6650 Driver  (.sh.tar) file  in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation, drivers, printing, lexmark

When I connected my printer to my pc, he found drivers & installed them.
I thought everything would work, but when I did a testpage, the pc acts likes he's doing the job great, but the printer didn't do anything.
So I searched on [`www.lexmark.be`](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&actp=DD_LIST&productCode=LEXMARK_X4975&id=DR20523&os=UBUNTU_10.04&oslocale=en_US&segment=DOWNLOAD&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en) & I found (I think) an additional download:

`lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar-1.`

Now it have to be extract, but I don't know where I have to do that.
(I'm new in Linux!)

Answer (score 0):

It is enclosed **script** (.sh.tar) File , so **extract** it , by Right-click and Extract option ,

Then simply `double click`  the **lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh** file ,which will provide Options window where you should

click the **"Run in Terminal"** button or run the script file via **command-line**.

Further Follow the Instructions if any , asked by installer.

They have provided the [Official instructions here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&actp=DD_LIST&productCode=LEXMARK_X4975&id=DR20523&os=UBUNTU_10.04&oslocale=en_US&segment=DOWNLOAD&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en). But it doesn't mentions Ubuntu 11.10 , which is currently your System, i guess it is Compiling so it will do.